# How do I set a "Case Type Category" in the Compucorp CiviCase extension

Tags: civicase

I see that the Compucorp CiviCase module adds a new "Case Type Category" field to the database.  However, I can see no way through the user interface to change it.  This means, e.g, that I can't add multiple workflows for the Prospecting extension.  Am I missing something?  Or is this only available via direct edits to the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a long discussion about the concept but the key comment is probably this one where it says it's not meant to be in the UI (or at least wasn't on the immediate roadmap) and such categories would be created by other extensions behind the scenes and specific to those extensions: https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues/630#note_16827

So it seems that yes at the moment you'd have to do it yourself outside the UI if you want your own categories.

Comment: Thansk @Demerit.  I guess my gripe is that the CiviProspect extension itself doesn't handle this by providing a mechanism to create case types with the category set correctly.

Comment: Are you running master of CiviProspect or the latest stable? It looks like there are several subsequent commits in master related to category that might address whatever the issue is. I haven't tried it myself.

Comment: Jon; its correct the case type category (of a case type) cannot be edited in the UI and hence does need to be done through the database for the time being. It's something we are thinking about the best way to attack in future. Feel free to add a github issue and we can give you an update there when we know more. Also yes there's quite a lot of work going on on master with respect to prospects and cases in general which will be released in mid Jan I would expect.